# How to automatically construct watch property based on data attributes in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have standard Vue.js component and I'd like to convert attributes in `data` property to watcher or in other words I want to construct a `watch` object based on `data` property attributes automatically

my idea looks something like this

```
 watch: {
    ...(() => {
      const watchers = {}

      Object.keys(this.$data).forEach(key => {
        watchers[key] = () => {
          new ProductNutrientUpdate(this).run()
        }
      })

      return watchers
    })(),
  },
```

the problem with this approach is that `this.$data` is not constructed yet

maybe there is some way how I can add watchers in `created` hook for example??

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Vue already watches properties of the data object (note if any of these values are themselves objects, I think you need to update the whole object, i.e. change its value to a shallow copy with the desired nested key-values).
Refer to: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html
You can then use the `update` lifecycle hook to watch for all changes to `data`: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated

Answer (score -2):

I was able to resolve a challenge using the following approach

```
created() {

    Object.keys(this.$data).forEach(key => {
      this.$watch(key, function() {
        // ... some logic to trigger on attribute change
      })
    })
}
```